# Range error for int in Java

Tags: java, casting, int

For the following values

```
long Count = 2151685171
int CurrentPosition = 849
int employeesLeft = 1276
```

Code below throws an indexOutOfBound error:

```
int EmployeeToBeEliminated = (int)(count+currentPosition-1)%employeesLeft;
```

Whereas if, written like this

```
count = (count+currentPosition-1)%employeesLeft;
int EmployeeToBeEliminated = (int)count;
```

there is no error thrown. But in the first case, after taking the modulus value is reduced to a range of `0` to `1276`, so it should be easily casted into an `int`. So why it throws an error ?

Comment: Check Integer.MAX_INT and also autoboxing: in first case all values cast into int while in the second case all value cast into long.

Comment: The code you included doesn't throw IndexOutOfBoundsException. You probably have some code where you use `EmployeeToBeEliminated` as an index of some Collection/array.

Comment: Your variable is called `Count` but your using `count` in your code. Same for  `currentPosition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is a `long` with a value outside the range of `int`.

A cast is applied to the (in this case parenthesized) operand immediately to the right of it. You could imagine the cast was parenthesized like the following:

```
( (int)(count+currentPosition-1) ) %employeesLeft
```

Casting the result of `(count+currentPosition-1)` to `int` results in an overflow.

What you want is:

```
(int)( (count+currentPosition-1)%employeesLeft )
```

Answer (score 0):

It first casts

```
(count+currentPosition-1)
```

to int, which breaks the +2.147.483.647 bound of an int and then tries to take the modulo.

Try:

```
int EmployeeToBeEliminated = (int)((count+currentPosition-1)%employeesLeft);
```

Comment: It is an int but because it casts  the long into the int (it's too large of a positive value for an int, so the cast makes it negative). When you modulus a negative by a positive then your result is a negative

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of operator precedence in Java.

In the first code sample, the code is processed in this order:

1. `(int)(count+currentPosition-1)`
2. `Result from 1 %employeesLeft;`

In the second code sample, the code is processed in this order:

1. `(count+currentPosition-1)%employeesLeft;`
2. `(int) Result from 1`

To get the same result, the first code sample should be written as:

`int EmployeeToBeEliminated = (int)((count+currentPosition-1)%employeesLeft);`

Note the new brackets added.

References: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html